# C++ OpenAL errors: missing OpenAL headers

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks

I'm running on Lubuntu using Code::Blocks with GCC, and despite installing the OpenAL dev packages with the commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libopenal-dev
sudo apt-get install libalut-dev
```

It reports the error "no such file or directory" when trying to include the headers. The #includes I've attempted (in-case it's a naming issue) are:

```
#include <OpenAl/al.h>
#include <OpenAl/alc.h>
```

-

```
#include <AL/al.h>
#include <AL/alc.h>
```

-

```
#include <al.h>
#include <alc.h>
```

Which all produce the same file/directory not found error.

What do I need to do in order to get GCC to 'see' the OpenAL headers?

**It's not a duplicate of:**

[How to compile OpenAL program with g++ (Ubuntu)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452676/how-to-compile-openal-program-with-g-ubuntu)

Because if you read the answer for that question is to "Make sure you have alut installed". If anyone took 3 seconds to read the top of this question they will see that it is **already installed**. Furthermore that question doesn't deal with CodeBlocks.

Comment: what's the output of `locate /al.h` ?

Comment: Also, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230601/g-unable-to-link-openal-libraries

Comment: @PatrickTrentin It's /usr/include/AL/al.h.

Comment: I was able to compile on Ubuntu using `#include <AL/al.h>` and the answer to the second link I posted. Did it work for you? Did you try using the full path?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: Code::Blocks 16.01, GCC 5.3/6.1. `<AL/al.h>`,`<AL/alc.h>` both found. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Digging further, it appears the file ALCheck.hpp (found in SFML's source code under the Audio folder) assumes it's located at #include <al.h>, when judging by Mike's comment it's located at <AL/al.h>. I'm not entirely sure why my project doesn't detect <AL/al.h>. (a new, fresh one works, but that doesn't help my developed project much). The workaround I discovered was to point codeblocks compiler search directories at /usr/include/AL. It strikes me however that SFML should have it defined as <AL/al.h> for linux, not <al.h>